# iOSのキーボードの種類によってoninputの発火回数が異なる

Tags: ios

### 概要

iOSのキーボードの種類によってoninputの発火回数が異なる

### Version

iOS: 15.3.1

### コード例

https://codepen.io/Ryotokubo/pen/VwrErLj
上記コードのoninput内でalertを呼び出して検証しています。

### 実際の挙動

正常

- キーボードタイプで数字を入力
  https://www.flickr.com/photos/195127769@N05/shares/30yv6r

異常

- デフォルトキーボードで数字を入力
  https://www.flickr.com/photos/195127769@N05/shares/90Q9ek

### 検証したこと/調べたこと

自身の調べ方が悪く、iOSのキーボードの仕様にあたる記事が見つかりませんでした。appleにfeedbackを求めても現在まで返答がありません。

情報が少ないとは思うのですが、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 実は回数の違いを調べたいのではなくて、回数が違っていても遅延実行等でメソッドやイベントが正しく動くようにしたいが実際のポイントじゃないかなと思います。（実はPCでもIMEにより発火のタイミングは違ったりします）実際はJSのライブラリ等を利用して、連続してイベントが発生したときにまとめたりする処理を書くのが基本です。[参考サイト](https://qiita.com/waterada/items/986660d31bc107dbd91c)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。このようなJSのライブラリで防げるものがあるのですね。IMEというものも初めて知りました。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。